# I cant start the first loop again on python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, pyautogui

First of all, I am insanely new to the python and probably my code will hurt your eyes. I am sorry.
My purpose on the code is simply making a filtering system with pyautogui and my first loop works fine but I needed to create a second loop due to too many statically nested blocks. I am ending the first loop with simply changing it to False but then when I wanna start again it fails and just finishes the task. I dont know how to fix and if anyone even can help me due to how chaotic the code is.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

should_restart = True

time.sleep(1)
while should_restart:
  try:
    loop2 = False
    yellow = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Yellow_FL.png', confidence=0.7)
    pyautogui.moveTo(yellow)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.mouseUp()
    pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
    print("Found1")
    continue
  except:
    try:
      green = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Green_FL.png', confidence=0.7, grayscale=True)
      pyautogui.moveTo(green)
      time.sleep(0.1)
      pyautogui.mouseDown()
      time.sleep(0.5)
      pyautogui.mouseUp()
      pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
      print("Found2")
      continue
    except:
      try:
        purple = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Purple_FL.png', confidence=0.7, grayscale=True)
        pyautogui.moveTo(purple)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.mouseUp()
        pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
        print("Found3")
        continue
      except:
        try:
          b_battery = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Brown_Battery.png', confidence=0.7, grayscale=True)
          pyautogui.moveTo(b_battery)
          time.sleep(0.1)
          pyautogui.mouseDown()
          time.sleep(0.5)
          pyautogui.mouseUp()
          pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
          print("Found4")
          continue
        except:
          try:
            g_battery = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('green_battery.png', confidence=0.7)
            pyautogui.moveTo(g_battery)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.mouseDown()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            pyautogui.mouseUp()
            pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
            print("Found5")
            continue
          except:
           try:
             P_Lens = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Purple_Lens.png', confidence=0.7, grayscale=True)
             pyautogui.moveTo(P_Lens)
             time.sleep(0.1)
             pyautogui.mouseDown()
             time.sleep(0.5)
             pyautogui.mouseUp()
             pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
             time.sleep(0.5)
             print("Found7")
             continue
           except:
             try:
               amp = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('yellow_amp.png', confidence=0.7)
               pyautogui.moveTo(amp)
               time.sleep(0.1)
               pyautogui.mouseDown()
               time.sleep(0.5)
               pyautogui.mouseUp()
               pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
               time.sleep(0.5)
               print("Found8")
               continue
             except:
               try:
                 styptic = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Styptic.png', confidence=0.7)
                 pyautogui.moveTo(styptic)
                 time.sleep(0.1)
                 pyautogui.mouseDown()
                 time.sleep(0.5)
                 pyautogui.mouseUp()
                 pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
                 time.sleep(0.5)
                 print("Found9")
                 continue
               except:
                 should_restart = False

loop2 = True
while loop2:
  try:
    lens_y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('yellow_lens.png', confidence=0.7)
    pyautogui.moveTo(lens_y)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.mouseUp()
    pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
    print("Found10")
    continue
  except:
    try:
      Syringe = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Syringe.png', confidence=0.7, grayscale=True)
      pyautogui.moveTo(Syringe)
      time.sleep(0.1)
      pyautogui.mouseDown()
      time.sleep(0.5)
      pyautogui.mouseUp()
      pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
      print("Found11")
      continue
    except:
      try:
        Auto = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('AutoBloodweb.png', confidence=0.7, grayscale=True)
        pyautogui.moveTo(Auto)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.mouseUp()
        pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
        print("Found12")
        time.sleep(4)
        should_restart = True
        time.sleep(1)
        loop2 = False
      except:
        try:
          Empty = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('EmptyBloo2aaadweb.png', confidence=0.7)
          break
        except:
          pass
```

I expected first loop would end and then 2nd loop would start, which it did, and then 2nd loop would stop and the first one would start again until the 'EmptyBloodweb.png' is detected.
Instead first loop is stopping 2nd loop is starting and then 2nd loop is stopping and thats all.

Comment: You have nothing in your code to tell it to go back to the first loop - everything executes from top to bottom in order. However, I think there are other issues at play here too, so in order to best advise, what is it you're trying to do? It looks like you are trying to search for a number of files on the screen?

Comment: All of those bare `try: except:`s will make your code impossible to actually debug since you can't ever know what actually went wrong.

Comment: What do you think would cause the program to start loop1 again after loop2 is finished? There is nothing there to make it do that. You could put the whole thing into another `while True:` block, which would cause it to restart. But I haven't really tried to follow your logic so I can't guarantee that's the design you really want.

Comment: I thought 'should_restart = True' would say the code to go back to the first loop. What I am trying to do is I want pyautogui to check for the files I put in order, and after it checked all the way to 'Auto' (Auto is always there but if there is files before that on the screen I want to it to prioritize those files first) I want it to restart the whole code from first loop.

Comment: `should_restart = True` will cause the first loop to keep looping, but once the second loop has started, the first loop is finished, and will not check `should_restart` again. You need something additional outside of and after the second loop to get the first loop started again.

Comment: I understand that now, thanks. I always need this whole 2 loop to be in order and check eachother so just adding the first loop again wouldnt fix the problem. I dont know how I can make the code go back to first loop now..

Comment: In general Python works by executing code top-down and does not go back to previous lines of code. The few exceptions to this include loops and function calls which direct the execution behaviour to specific sections of code. (Python has no `GOTO` command and for good reason). The way your code is structured you may benefit a lot from extracting the behaviour into a couple of functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the actual logic you're going for is, but if my crystal ball and educated guess is right, you want to try and click those things in sequence, starting again from the first one if a click fails (by way of not finding the thing)?

If that's the case, I'd refactor this to something like the below.

The idea is that `find_and_click` tries to do the finding-and-clicking, returning False if it couldn't find the thing (and it will happily raise exceptions if the actual move-to/mouse-down/mouse-up sequence fails).

Then, the two loops in `main()` are restarted using `continue` if any click fails (the helper function returns `False`).

If the two loops are dependent, you could extract them into two functions of the same sort: if any step fails, retry the other loop, and so on.

```
import time

import pyautogui


def find_and_click(png, grayscale=False):
    print(f"Looking for {png}...")
    try:
        obj = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(png, confidence=0.7, grayscale=grayscale)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Could not find {png}: {e}")
        return False
    pyautogui.moveTo(obj)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.mouseUp()
    pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
    return True


def main():
    while True:
        print("Starting loop 1...")
        if not find_and_click("Yellow_FL.png"):
            continue
        if not find_and_click("Green_FL.png", grayscale=True):
            continue
        if not find_and_click("Purple_FL.png", grayscale=True):
            continue
        if not find_and_click("Brown_Battery.png", grayscale=True):
            continue
        if not find_and_click("green_battery.png"):
            continue
        if not find_and_click("Purple_Lens.png", grayscale=True):
            continue
        if not find_and_click("yellow_amp.png"):
            continue
        if not find_and_click("Styptic.png"):
            continue
        break

    while True:
        print("Starting loop 2...")
        if not find_and_click("yellow_lens.png"):
            continue
        if not find_and_click("Syringe.png", grayscale=True):
            continue
        if not find_and_click("AutoBloodweb.png", grayscale=True):
            continue
        break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If the idea is to just click these things in order, waiting forever until they appear, then this simplifies to

```
import time
from itertools import count

import pyautogui


def find_and_click(png, grayscale=False):
    print(f"Looking for {png}...")
    try:
        obj = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(png, confidence=0.7, grayscale=grayscale)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Could not find {png}: {e}")
        return False
    pyautogui.moveTo(obj)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.mouseUp()
    pyautogui.moveTo(1200, 600)
    return True


def wait_for_find_and_click(png, grayscale=False):
    for attempt in count(1):
        print(f"Attempt {attempt} to find {png}...")
        if find_and_click(png, grayscale):
            break
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    while True:
        wait_for_find_and_click("Yellow_FL.png")
        wait_for_find_and_click("Green_FL.png", grayscale=True)
        wait_for_find_and_click("Purple_FL.png", grayscale=True)
        wait_for_find_and_click("Brown_Battery.png", grayscale=True)
        wait_for_find_and_click("green_battery.png")
        wait_for_find_and_click("Purple_Lens.png", grayscale=True)
        wait_for_find_and_click("yellow_amp.png")
        wait_for_find_and_click("Styptic.png")
        wait_for_find_and_click("yellow_lens.png")
        wait_for_find_and_click("Syringe.png", grayscale=True)
        wait_for_find_and_click("AutoBloodweb.png", grayscale=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: First of all thank you a lot for this, my issue with this code is the fact that its always trying to find the first image and if fails keeps trying to find that image until it can. What I need is pretty much checking if the image is there and if not then just continue to the next until it can find the last one (which last one 'AutoBloodWeb' is always on the screen). So instead of keep repeating the line until it can find the png how can I make it in this code so its just skipping if it didnt find the png?

Comment: Instead of `continue` (which restarts the loop), `pass` (which does nothing and continues to the next statement) :)

Comment: In that way it works but it stops when it reaches to the last line 'AutoBloodWeb'. If I switch the last pass to continue then it starts from loop 2 and not loop 1..

Comment: If it's supposed to do loop 1 again after loop 2 finishes, wrap the two loops in yet another `while True`.

Comment: The thing is, I want this two loops to be in order and just keep repeating itself infintely. If I do what you said wouldnt be stopping at some point unless I do the code like insanely long? I am sorry for if its a stupid question.

Comment: The code doesn't need to be long for the run to be infinitely long. Consider e.g. `while True: time.sleep(1)` – that will run until the end of time (so long as it's not interrupted) with 2 lines.

Comment: Anyway, I added another implementation which might be what you're after, but it's a bit hard to tell.

Comment: I am aware but it was just not possible for me to restart the loop after I 'break' or turn it into 'False' and stop the loop. I just want it to check all the pngs apart from 'AutoBloodweb.png' and if they are there just click on them and if not click on 'AutoBloodweb.png'. I think the adjustment to the code you made will work if I just change the 'AutoBloodweb.png' to click if everything else is not found. Just need to figure out how to do that.. But thank you a lot for your help already

Comment: The last code definetly made the job done. I just needed to change everything else but 'AutoBloodweb.png' to 'find_and_click' and now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.